# Order array of windows by z order

Tags: x11

I read this about stack order / z order of windows on X11:

> To obtain good interoperability between different Desktop Environments, the following layered stacking order is recommended, from the bottom:
>
> ```
> windows of type _NET_WM_TYPE_DESKTOP
>
> windows having state _NET_WM_STATE_BELOW
>
> windows not belonging in any other layer
>
> windows of type _NET_WM_TYPE_DOCK (unless they have state _NET_WM_TYPE_BELOW) and windows having state _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE
>
> focused windows having state _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN
> ```

I was able to use get the `_NET_WM_USER_TIME` atom to order windows. I used `XQuerySubtree` and `XGetWindowProperty`. But it's not the best solution, as lots of times it gets the window before the most recent window. Code here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/60aab0a96f060240614f

I was wondering if there was a way to get windows by z order?

Comment: QueryTree should be enough? "This request returns the root, the parent, and the children of the window. The children are listed in bottom-to-top stacking order."

Comment: Oh no way! I didn't know it was by default listed as bottom to top thats super cool thanks man! This is an xy question but is there any way to do a quick test if the window is visible (meaning like i can find it in the alt+tab menu?)

Comment: Don't know out the top of my head, might be wm/de specific. Try to read http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html

Comment: I guess the answer is "All _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL root children"

Comment: Thank you man very much for that! I'll look into that and report back how it works out :)

Comment: @AndreySidorov it worked!! Thank you very much! Can you please move to answer so i can select as solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comments:

[XQueryTree](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html) does return children sorted by stacking order:

> The children are listed in current stacking order, from bottommost (first) to topmost (last)

Answer to "is there any way to do a quick test if the window is visible in task bar / task switcher" is "check if it's [_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472629520) window"